# To move a qbutton on a form

Tags: python, python-3.x, pyqt, qpushbutton

I build my own button class from Qbutton and want to arrange a batch of mybuttons on my form. The issue is they just showed on the bottom right corner of my form - totally ignore my "move" method. (Python 3 + Qt5) Thanks!

```
Blist = [
["Quit",1250,750],
["LoadAny",1250,850]
        ]
class lb(QPushButton):
    def __init__(self, t, parent=None):
        QPushButton.__init__(self, t, parent)
        self.setText(t.split("_")[1])
        self.setFixedHeight(ButtonH)
        self.setFixedWidth(ButtonW)
        self.setStyleSheet("background-color:white;")
        self.setObjectName(t.split("_")[0])
        self.setFont(QFont("Times", 12, QFont.StyleNormal))

class MyWindow(QWidget):
       …     
        buttons = {}
        self.layout = QVBoxLayout(self)        
        for i in range(len(Blist)):
            buttons[i] = lb('%d_%s' %(i,Blist[i][0]))
            self.layout.addWidget(buttons[i])
            buttons[i].move(Blist[i][1],Blist[i][2])
            buttons[i].clicked.connect(self.bclick)
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When you add a widget to a layout, this is responsible for managing the location policy, in your case you have added them to a QVBoxLayout, so they will be distributed vertically:

[image]

If you want to add it and you can move it freely do not use a layout, you must pass as a parent to the widget where you want to place it since it will be placed in the upper corner but now if you can use the `move()` function:

```
Blist = [
    ["Quit",50,250],
    ["LoadAny",250,350]
]
ButtonH = 40
ButtonW = 80

class lb(QPushButton):
    def __init__(self, t, parent=None):
        QPushButton.__init__(self, t, parent)
        self.setText(t.split("_")[1])
        self.setFixedHeight(ButtonH)
        self.setFixedWidth(ButtonW)
        self.setStyleSheet("background-color:white;")
        self.setObjectName(t.split("_")[0])
        self.setFont(QFont("Times", 12, QFont.StyleNormal))

class MyWindow(QWidget):
    def __init__(self, parent=None):
        QWidget.__init__(self, parent)
        buttons = {}
        #self.layout = QVBoxLayout(self)        
        for i in range(len(Blist)):
            buttons[i] = lb('%d_%s' %(i,Blist[i][0]), self)
            #self.layout.addWidget(buttons[i])
            buttons[i].move(Blist[i][1],Blist[i][2])
            buttons[i].clicked.connect(self.bclick)

    def bclick(self):
        print("click")
```

[image]

Comment: Thank you @eyllanesc for your thoughtful answer. It worked!

Comment: @LarryZ Please do not forget to mark my answer as correct.